# MySQL one-to-many relationship. Different table, or PHP handling?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, relationship

I am creating a MySQL database in which I have two tables, one for blogs, and one for their locations. What I have done is a field in `blogs` which is a string of location ids separated by commas: 1,5,7. Then in my PHP script I can explode() that string and get the locations.

The problem comes if I want to look for all blogs of a location using a MySQL query.

Should I create another table for the relationship? Maybe blog 1 location 1, blog 1 location 5, blog 1 location 7. Three rows to represent the former example. That way I would only select the blogs in that location in the query. The other way I would have to select ALL the blogs and check each of them one by one.

What do you think is faster and cleaner?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you should create another - intersection - table. Actually, it looks like m:n relationship (as location X seems to be usable in more than one blog). Otherwise you should be able to use `location` table to link it with a single blog item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct that the best way to do this in a Relational Database setting is the 3rd table, sometimes called a Junction Table, to handle the relationships between Blogs and Locations.  What you describe is a many-to-many relationship (or a one-to-many relationship that is going both ways).

[Here](http://sqlrelationship.com/many-to-many-relationship/) is a link describing it a little better than me.

Comment: For being the first, and for the link, I choose you answer. Thank you! You are all right, I mistook one-to-many and many-to-many :P Any tips about keys or searching them? I want to learn to do this the best possible way.

Comment: Once you design the tables and populate it with data, you should be able to join pretty easily to get the data you'll need.

One thing I suggest is to have a primary key, even if it is an auto incrment integer, to identify the unique row of Blog_Location    so the table should really have 3 fields:   BlogLocationID (UNIQUE), BlogID, LocationID    - then depending on your data perhaps this combination could use a date field  BlogLocationDate   (but I'm not quite sure without being familiar w/ your data)

Comment: I am trying to build the query. What I want is to get a list of blogs, and next to each blog, a list of locations (their locations), by their name. So, I have a table of blogs, which have name and id (the simple case), a table of locations which have name and id too, and a junction table which has blog and location (and the id you suggested). How can I, in a single query, obtain in every row, a blog, with name, id, and list of locations? Thank you!

Comment: SELECT *
FROM tblBlog B
INNER JOIN tblBlogLocation BL
ON B.BlogID = BL.BlogID
INNER JOIN tblLocation L
ON BL.LocationID = L.LocationID;

Answer (score 2):

Different table is cleaner. As a matter of fact, it's the only choice, as it's the very basics of relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

A third table to represent the relationships is the only way to go really.